# Want to display image from the input file when user makes post request

Tags: node.js, express

I want to display the image from the input type file when user makes post request to another ejs file

```
//making post request
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="itemImg" />



app.post('/sell', (req, res) => {
res.render('sell' , {itemImage: req.body.itemImg})
})
// trying to display it but it displays the title or whatever
    <img src="<%= itemImg %>" alt="">
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add more detail: Do you want to display the image only _once_, in response to the upload request? Or do you want to keep it on your server and subsequently display it on another page (which)?

Comment: i want to create a emcomerce website so i want to store the image in database when user uploads it